# Node + Mongo / Mongoose text search score doesn't take a full int? Is it possible to filter low scores another way?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a text search as follows:

```
 const matches = await Site.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          clientId: req.user.client_id,
          $text: { $search: req.body.searchTerms }
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 0,
          score: { $meta: 'textScore' }
        }
      },
      {
        $match: {
          score: { $gt: req.body.wordsCount }
        }
      },
      { $group: { _id: null, myCount: { $sum: 1 } } },
      { $sort: { score: { $meta: 'textScore' } } }
    ]);

    const sites = await Site.find(
      {
        clientId: req.user.client_id,
        $text: { $search: req.body.searchTerms }
      },
      { score: { $meta: 'textScore' } },
      {
        $match: {
          score: { $gt: req.body.wordsCount }
        }
      }
    )
      .sort({ score: { $meta: 'textScore' } })
      .limit(20);
```

I'm  basically obtaining:

- Count of matches
- Array of actual documents

And I'm trying to add stricter matching criteria on the score, but it seems I can't just put in a number as I've seen in my own tests, it depends on the total number of words you're searching, so I want the match to always be wordsCount - 1 unless the wordscount is 1;

For some reason it seems it doesn't like it if I have a full number there as in, 1 instead of 1.0 which to me makes no sense as they're practically the same.

I know I should include the documents in the aggregate itself but I'm still getting the hang of that and haven't been successful in my attempts so far.

EDIT: If I just put req.body.wordsCount - 0.5 it works... how can mongodb/mongoose possibly not take integers for this?